# Desabilitar required do data annotation via jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou precisando desabilitar o `required` do `dataannotation` via jquery, e preciso desabilitar também o data-required, este eu consegui, mas o required não, estou tentando fazer desta forma:

```
$("#Contato").attr("required", "false");
$("#Contato").attr("data-required", "false");
```

Já tentei assim:

```
 $("#Contato").attr("data-val-required", "false");
```

Mas nenhuma forma funciona. Como posso aproveitar o dataannotation e dependendo da condição desativar ?

Comment: Já tentou `$("#Contato").removeAttr("required");`?

Comment: @Sam já sim, e ocorre o mesmo problema.

Comment: Se não me engano o **false** é sem aspas não?!

Comment: @LeAndrade mesmo assim também não deu, foi minha primeira tentativa.

Comment: Da forma que colocou na pergunta, parece que vc está querendo remover o atributo do elemento, o que funcionaria perfeitamente o que coloquei no comentário anterior. Agora, se vc quer manipular um componente ou plugin, aí já é outra coisa. Teria que mostrar código de como está usando o componente.

Comment: @Sam eu disse que teria uma condição, desculpe se não ficou tão claro, até então consegui fazer desta maneira `if (Tipo == 'Outros') {
            $('#TipoPessoa').rules('remove', 'required');
            $("#TipoPessoa").attr("data-required", "false");} else {
            $('#TipoPessoa').rules('add', 'required');
            $("#TipoPessoa").attr("data-required", "true");}` Não sei se é a melhor forma, mas foi a que funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#firstname').prop('required', false);
$('#firstname').removeAttr('data-required');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text"  required  data-required name="firstname"  id="firstname" ><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" required  data-required name="lastname" id="lastname">
</form>
```